# How do I extract only the desired files from tar.gz?

Tags: linux, jar, gzip, extract, tar

I have a .tar.gz file which has multiple folders underneath. Each folder has multiple files and I only want to extract the *SNAPSHOT*.jar from all the folders it has underneath.

I tried using wildcards but its not helping. Ex:

```
    tar -xf samplejars.tar.gz --wildcards "*SNAPSHOT*.jar"
```

samplejars.tar.gz has many folders and I only want to extract *SNAPSHOT*.jar. How do I do that?

Note: All the jars have unique/different names.

Comment: [P.S. Answer to [this][1] question by user 'ford' answers my question perfectly]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295771/how-do-i-extract-files-without-folder-structure-using-tar?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested it with the following folder structure:

```
data/
data/a
data/a/ANOTHER_SNAPSHOT.jar
data/b
data/c
data/c/SNAPSHOT.jar
data/d
data/e
data/f
data/f/SNAPSHOT.jar.with.extension
data/g
data/g/SNAPSHOT.jar
data/h
```

The following wildcard mask works and extract **only** the files matching exactly **SNAPSHOT.jar** not SNAPSHOT.jar.with.extension and ANOTHER_SNAPSHOT.jar

```
tar -xf data.tar.gz --wildcards "*/SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

**Result:**

```
data/c/SNAPSHOT.jar
data/g/SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: Thanks Florian, this helps to a certain extent.
But, is it possible to get just the jars and not the folders out of the tar.gz?
Like, the sample output from your answer has the two SNAPSHOT.jars under the folders data/c/ and data/g/. How do I get just the .jars and not the folders?

Comment: In theory this is possible. Some ways are discussed in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295771/how-do-i-extract-files-without-folder-structure-using-tar

The problem is, you are looking for multiples jars with the **same** name. Therefore they can't be extracted into the same folder.

Comment: Thanks Florian. The link you shared gave me what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file with the pattern you are looking for:

```
echo "*SNAPSHOT*.jar" > target
```

If you have multiple patterns, you can add multiple lines to your target file

```
echo "*.md" >> target
```

Then you can use the --files-from switch:

```
tar -xf samplejars.tar.gz --files-from=filename
```

I tested with

```
data/
data/a/
data/a/ANOTHER_SNAPSHOT.jar
data/b/
data/c/
data/c/SNAPSHOT.jar
data/d/
data/e/
data/f/
data/f/SNAPSHOT.jar.with.extension
data/g/
data/g/SNAPSHOT-2.jar
data/g/SNAPSHOT.jar
data/h/
```

**Result**

```
data/a/ANOTHER_SNAPSHOT.jar
data/c/SNAPSHOT.jar
data/g/SNAPSHOT-2.jar
data/g/SNAPSHOT.jar
```

If all the files have unique filenames, as the OP said, you can use --strip-components to remove the file structure

```
tar -xf samplejars.tar.gz --files-from=filename --strip-components 2
```

With my data, the result was:

```
ANOTHER_SNAPSHOT.jar
SNAPSHOT.jar
SNAPSHOT-2.jar
```

Because I did not have unique names, one of the SNAPSHOT.jar files was overwritten in the --strip-components step.

Comment: Thanks @Dan Meigs, this helps to a certain extent.
But, is it possible to get just the jars and not the folders out of the tar.gz?
Like, the sample output from your answer has the two SNAPSHOT.jars under the folders data/c/ and data/g/ etc. How do I get just the .jars and not the folders?

Comment: I updated my answer based on the link provided by @Florian Schlag

Answer (score 0):

You can use xargs for that :

```
tar -tf data.tar.gz | grep SNAPSHOT.jar | xargs tar -xf data.tar.gz
```

Then, to move all the files to the root directory

```
find archive_root_dir -type f -exec mv -i {} . \;
```

Comment: Thanks @blue112, this helps to a certain extent.
But, is it possible to get just the jars and not the folders out of the tar.gz?
I mean, the command you shared brings out the folder structure from the tar.gz. Can we get just the jars out of the tar.gz, and no folder structure?

Comment: @Dhiraj How would you handle two jars named the same way ?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that :)  The jars have unique names, so that's not a problem.